# Why javascript update is inserting new record instead of updating existing record

Tags: javascript, html

I want to perform a CRUD operation in javascript.

I have an update button when I click on the button I see the record gets filled on the text field but when I submit the form instead of updating the same record a new record gets generated.

I would appreciate a recommendation how can I improve the code in a much better way.

Could you please help?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CRUD</title>
 
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>ADD USER</h3>
      <form id="form"  >
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="age" type="number" name="age" min="10" max="100" placeholder="Age" required>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btn" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>USERS</h3>
      <table id="userTable" class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th colspan="3">Age</th>
        </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update User</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){

var selectedRow = null;  //global variable
var users = [];

var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
//console.log(btn);
var form = document.querySelector('#form');


        btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
            

        var obj = {
                    name: document.querySelector('#name').value,
                    address: document.querySelector('#address').value,
                    age: document.querySelector('#age').value,
            }//obj ends here

            users.push(obj);
            //console.log(users);


            var userTable = document.querySelector('#userTable');
            var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');  

            tbody.appendChild(tr);
            

            for(var i =0; i< users.length; i++){
        

                var tdata1 = document.createElement('td');
                var tdata2 = document.createElement('td');
                var tdata3 = document.createElement('td');
                var tdata4 = document.createElement('td');
                var tdata5 = document.createElement('td');


                var update = document.createElement("button");
                update.innerText = 'Update';
                update.id = "update"+i;
                tdata4.appendChild(update);

                update.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                    
                 
                 selectedRow = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;


                 document.getElementById("name").value = selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
                 document.getElementById("address").value = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
                 document.getElementById("age").value = selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML;
 

                tdata1.innerText = selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
                tdata2.innerText = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
                tdata3.innerText = selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML;

               
                 });

                var del = document.createElement("button");
                del.innerText = 'Delete';
                del.id = "delete"+i;
                tdata5.appendChild(del);

                tdata1.innerText = users[i].name;
                tdata2.innerText = users[i].address;
                tdata3.innerText = users[i].age;
                
                del.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                console.log("delete working on id ", e.target.id);
                if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?')) {
                row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
                document.getElementById("userTable").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
                //resetForm();
                     }
                });

                
                form.reset();

                }
                   tr.appendChild(tdata1);
                   tr.appendChild(tdata2);
                   tr.appendChild(tdata3);
                   tr.appendChild(tdata4);
                   tr.appendChild(tdata5);

        });// btn event listener ends here


    } // window onload ends here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really doing any check if the `update` button was clicked. Add something like that:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var selectedRow = null; //global variable
  var users = [];
  var toUpdate = null;


  var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
  //console.log(btn);
  var form = document.querySelector('#form');


  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {


    var obj = {
      name: document.querySelector('#name').value,
      address: document.querySelector('#address').value,
      age: document.querySelector('#age').value,
    } //obj ends here

    if (toUpdate) {
      toUpdate.cells[0].innerHTML = obj.name;
      toUpdate.cells[1].innerHTML = obj.address;
      toUpdate.cells[2].innerHTML = obj.age;
      toUpdate = null;
      form.reset();
      return;
    }

    users.push(obj);
    //console.log(users);


    var userTable = document.querySelector('#userTable');
    var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    tbody.appendChild(tr);


    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {


      var tdata1 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata2 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata3 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata4 = document.createElement('td');
      var tdata5 = document.createElement('td');


      var update = document.createElement("button");
      update.innerText = 'Update';
      update.id = "update" + i;
      tdata4.appendChild(update);

      update.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

        selectedRow = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;

        document.getElementById("name").value = selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("address").value = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("age").value = selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML;
        toUpdate = selectedRow;

        tdata1.innerText = selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
        tdata2.innerText = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
        tdata3.innerText = selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML;


      });

      var del = document.createElement("button");
      del.innerText = 'Delete';
      del.id = "delete" + i;
      tdata5.appendChild(del);

      tdata1.innerText = users[i].name;
      tdata2.innerText = users[i].address;
      tdata3.innerText = users[i].age;

      del.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log("delete working on id ", e.target.id);
        if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?')) {
          row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
          document.getElementById("userTable").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
          //resetForm();
        }
      });


      form.reset();

    }
    tr.appendChild(tdata1);
    tr.appendChild(tdata2);
    tr.appendChild(tdata3);
    tr.appendChild(tdata4);
    tr.appendChild(tdata5);

  }); // btn event listener ends here


} // window onload ends here
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CRUD</title>

</head>

<body>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>ADD USER</h3>
        <form id="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="age" type="number" name="age" min="10" max="100" placeholder="Age" required>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btn" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3>USERS</h3>
        <table id="userTable" class="table table-striped">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th colspan="3">Age</th>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate your reply! Could you please share your email or ID. where I can tag you next time if I face any issue. Thanks again